# Getting wordpress posts with react shows special chars instead of apostrophe

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, headless-cms

I am getting what I am assuming is json data from a wordpress blog endpoint like so:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

I am looping through and showing the tiles for now:

```
<div>{posts && posts.map((post) => <h1>{post.title.rendered}</h1>)}</div>
```

But the post titles are not displaying properly. For example the word ***Don't*** shows `Don&#8217;t`

I have discovered that I can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to fix this issue but is it safe? The fact that it has the word 'dangerously' in it is worrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the way to go about this - but I will go into more detail as to why "dangerously" is in "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" and hopefully that will help you make an informed decision for your situation.

---

What `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` does is render any HTML string given to it within the DOM element.

For example:

```
<h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.title.rendered}} />
```

(as an aside, note the `__html` key has two underscores)

Will properly render the string `Don&#8217;t` to `Don't`.

This is all pretty harmless, however, if, for example, the value of `post.title.rendered` could be set by an untrusted party (such as an arbitrary user), and if this arbitrary user wanted to do some damage, they could enter a string such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
// Do evil stuff
console.log('I did some evil stuff');
</script>
```

This code would then be executed by the browser when the page loads - because React would have generated the following DOM:

```
<h1>
   <script type="text/javascript>
   // Do evil stuff
   console.log('I did some evil stuff');
   </script>
</h1>
```

---

So with all that in mind, if you are **sure** that the value of this field is within **your** control (and not anyone else's) and you also **know** that there will not be any arbitrary code in these strings, then go ahead and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

However, if there is the possibility that someone besides yourself could manipulate this field, I would instead look to something like [decode-html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decode-html-entities) - this way you can have the presentation you want, without compromising your app/users.